# Two and more columns inside span

Tags: html, css

I need to have a panel with list of values.  Each value have a label. A label must be displayed above the value. Each label must be aligned on the left side.

It must look like this:

```
Label 1        Label 2
Value 1        Value 2
```

Here is my code - [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/boeAsWyCoGJNzv1XRbZe?p=preview)

```
<div>
   <span>
     <span class="a">title 1</span>
     <input type="text" class="b" />
   </span>
   <span>
     <span class="c">title 2</span>
     <input class="d" />
   </span>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
span.a {
  color: red;
}

input.b {
  display: block;
}

span.c {
  color: blue;
}

input.d {
  display: block;
}
```

What is the best way to fix it ?

Comment: `div > span { float: left; }`

Comment: You could give your `span` a default width, and then align them left `float: left`. Or use a `Table`. And down forget to set `display: block;`. (Might better use divs)

Comment: @Xyv, I am not sure I understood correctly, but it doesn't work https://plnkr.co/edit/nGtRySJa6nvpFFu9OxJM?p=preview

Comment: @demas moment please, I'll work it out

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/V53Ij6T12cavCwnc5qyb?p=preview

Comment: Isn't this what a `table` is for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS Tables is an option here (if an actual `table` can't be used)

```css
.table {
  display: table;
}
.col {
  display: table-cell;
}
.col > * {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <span class="col">
     <span class="a">title 1</span>
  <input type="text" class="b" />
  </span>
  <span class="col">
     <span class="c">title 2</span>
  <input class="d" />
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try a flex layout.

Here is an example.

If you want your span elements to wrap on smaller screens add `flex-flow: row wrap` to the `.wrapper` class.

```css
/* Styles go here */

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.flex-item {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

span.a {
  color: red;
}

input.b {
  color: green;
  display: block;
}

span.c {
  color: blue;
}

input.d {
  color: black;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="flex-item">
    <span class="a">title 1</span>
    <input type="text" class="b" />
  </span>
  <span class="flex-item">
    <span class="c">title 2</span>
    <input class="d" />
  </span>
  <span class="flex-item">
    <span class="c">title 3</span>
    <input class="d" />
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments I wrote out the example for better readability:

```
div > span {
    display: block;
    width: 200px; /* Could be any with you desire */
    float: left;
}
```

Is this what you mean: https://plnkr.co/edit/4epj5b53JYlJMVZbudJb?p=preview